# $\sum_{n=1 }^{+\infty }a_{n}$ and $\sum_{n=m }^{+\infty }a_{n}$ or converge together or diverge together

Tags: calculus

Prove that series $$\sum_{n=1 }^{+\infty }a_{n}$$ and $$\sum_{n=m }^{+\infty }a_{n}$$ or converge together or diverge together. When they converge, find $\alpha$ to we have $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty }a_{n}=\alpha + \sum_{n=m}^{+\infty }a_{n}$$

---

METHOD 1:

I will prove that $\sum_{n=1 }^{+\infty }a_{n}$ converges $\Leftrightarrow$ $\sum_{n=m }^{+\infty }a_{n}$ converges.

We have the nth partial sums of seri $\sum_{n=1 }^{+\infty }a_{n}$ is $s_{n}=\sum_{k=1 }^{n }a_{k}$ and the nth partial sums of seri $\sum_{n=m }^{+\infty }a_{n}$ is $t_{n+m-1}=\sum_{k=m }^{n+m-1 }a_{k}$ ***(or  the nth partial sums of seri $\sum_{n=m }^{+\infty }a_{n}$ is$t_{n}=\sum_{k=m }^{n}a_{k}$ ? I think I have problem with this)***

We prove that the sequence $(s_{n})$  converges $\Leftrightarrow$ sequence $(t_{n+m-1})$ converges

First, suppose we have the sequence $(s_{n})$  converges and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }s_{n}=b$. We have $\forall \epsilon >0,\exists  n_{0}\in \mathbb{N}, \forall n\geq n_{0}:|s_{n}-b|<\epsilon$. Cause $n+m-1\geq n \geq n_{0}$ so $|s_{n+m-1}-b|< \epsilon \Rightarrow |t_{n+m-1}+ \sum_{k=1 }^{m-1 }a_{k}-b|< \epsilon$.

Therefore $\forall \epsilon >0,\exists  n_{0}\in \mathbb{N}, \forall n\geq n_{0}:|t_{n+m-1}-( b-\sum_{k=1 }^{m-1 }a_{k})|<\epsilon$. So $(t_{n+m-1})$ converges and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }t_{n+m-1}=b-\sum_{k=1 }^{m-1 }a_{k} $

Second, suppose we have the sequence $(t_{n})$  converges and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }t_{n}=b$. I'm stuck at this.

Please tell me where I was wrong. Thank you very much.

---

METHOD 2:

We have $$\sum_{n=1 }^{\infty}a_{n}=\sum_{n=1 }^{m-1 }a_{n}+\sum_{n=m }^{\infty}a_{n}$$
Because $\sum_{n=1 }^{m-1 }a_{n}$ is a finite sum (constant) so $\sum_{n=1 }^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges $\Leftrightarrow$ $\sum_{n=m }^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges.

It is right?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I've just edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We fix a $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Then:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n=  \sum_{n=1}^{m-1}a_n+ \sum_{n=m}^{N} a_n $$

Note that $\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}a_n$ is a finite sum.

So what can we say?

Comment: Depending on how picky one is, this isn't *strictly* true. What is true, however, is that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N a_n = \Big(\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} a_n + \sum_{n=m}^N a_n\Big)
$$
with some care how to deal with $N < m$.

Comment: That said, I'm probably being annoying pedantic here.

Comment: May be  the nth partial sum of $\sum_{n = m}^\infty a_n$ is $\sum_{k = m}^{n} a_k$. If this, I can complete this exercise. Thank you.